# fish - Maximum recursion depth reached with tab-complete

Tags: alias, autocomplete, fish

With my fish shell, I have defined the alias

```bsh
alias black='command black -l 110'
```

When I type `black` in my shell and start to tab-complete, I get the error

> complete: maximum recursion depth reached

The same thing happens with similar aliases such as

```bsh
alias readelf='command readelf -W'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I enter

```
alias readelf='command readelf -W'
```

into a fish shell, this is what fish does with it:

```
$ type -a readelf
readelf is a function with definition
# Defined via `source`
function readelf --wraps='command readelf -W' --description 'alias readelf=command readelf -W'
  command readelf -W $argv;
end
```

The `--wraps` argument, which controls completions, looks wrong.

Since fish creates functions for aliases, just create the function yourself:

```
function readelf --wraps=readelf
  command readelf -W $argv
end
```

Ref: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/function.html

Comment: Still getting the error.  After typing in exactly what you recommended, `type -a readelf` produces `function readelf --wraps='command readelf -W' ...`

Comment: You're running this in a fish that already has the alias loaded, so the wrapping remains in place. Replace your alias with the definition at the bottom and restart fish. Ideally call your function something *else*, it's always better when names refer to the normal things.